# What am I doing wrong? Why do the actions not work while they're supposed to?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I've been using python for around 2 months, I've been mostly working with tkinter but today I've decided to try out turtle. I'm currently working on a clicker game where when you click a mouse(an image), you receive 1 click, what I'm having problem is that when for example, when you get 10 clicks, something to be printed out, but it isn't working. I've tried:

```
if clicks == 10:
    print("10 clicks")
    
elif clicks == 20:
    print("20 click")
```

but it's not working. They only work if I change the default start clicks in the code itself. Here's the whole code:

```
#Imports
import turtle

#Window basic settings
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Clicker")
wn.bgcolor("light blue")
turtle.setup(800, 500)
wn.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False)

#Shape register
wn.register_shape("mouse.gif")

#Mouse
mouse = turtle.Turtle()
mouse.shape("mouse.gif")
mouse.speed(0)

#Clicks
clicks = 0

#Click counter
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0, -200)
pen.write(f"Clicks:{clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))

def clicked(x, y):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f"Clicks:{clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))
    
mouse.onclick(clicked)

#Actions
if clicks == 10:
    print("10 clicks")
    
elif clicks == 20:
    print("20 click")

#Window main loop
wn.mainloop()
```

Is the problem the fact that when you click, it writes a whole new text and doesn't change the current one? How do I fix it?

Comment: No, the problem is that both `if`s are checked way before you get a chance to increase `clicks` by any number. When UI shows up, you are already in `wn.mainloop()`.

Comment: Please, edit your question title in order to give specific information about the code error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` is executed only once. You have to move it to the `clicked` function.

```
import turtle

#Window basic settings
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Clicker")
wn.bgcolor("light blue")
turtle.setup(800, 500)
wn.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False)

#Shape register
wn.register_shape("mouse.gif")

#Mouse
mouse = turtle.Turtle()
mouse.shape("mouse.gif")
mouse.speed(0)

#Clicks
clicks = 0

#Click counter
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0, -200)
pen.write(f"Clicks:{clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))

def clicked(x, y):
    print("clicked")
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f"Clicks:{clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))

    if clicks == 10:
        print("10 clicks")
        
    elif clicks == 20:
        print("20 click")

    
mouse.onclick(clicked)


#Actions

#Window main loop
wn.mainloop()
```